# Go through list of files and replace a string

Tags: linux, scripting, ksh

I have a file with a list of files in which a replacement of a string has to be done.This is KSH

file_to_be_parsed:

```
some_directory1/file_name1
some_directory2/file_name2
.
.
.
so on
```

I have to read *file_to_be_parsed*, open each file which is on each line and replace a string in all the files listed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the question is fairly vague, and there's no expectation/preference re the framework listed, here's one approach:

```
while read name
do
  sed -i 's/old_string/new_string/g' $name
done < file_to_be_parsed
```